# Make macports default to installing universal binaries?

Tags: macos, macports

I use macports to install C libraries that various Haskell libraries depend on. Unfortunately, the current version of Haskell only works under 32 bit in OS X, but other things using these libraries are 64 bits. So every library I install I end up using the +universal switch on. Can I make +universal the default for packages I install with macports?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The MacPorts Wiki has an answer](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/buildUniversal).

> You can add +universal to your /opt/local/etc/macports/variants.conf to ask MacPorts to build all ports you install with that variant, without having to remember to type it at every install command. However, some ports have not yet been tested as universal binaries and may not build properly. Or they may build but then not work on the foreign architecture.